# Insert query does't insert data to mysql database table

Tags: php

i have a recipe table and ingredient table the primary key of both tables are auto increament and primary key of recipe is foreign key in ingredient. i post data from html to php.Note that my ingredient textboxes are generated dynamically and successfully post the data to php script. posted data is correct when i insert this data to table my query working fine but data is not added to mysql table. my code and output is

```
$sql = "insert into recipe (rec_id, Name, Overview,category, Time, Image) values ('', '$name','$overview','$category','$time','$TARGET_PATH')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Could not insert data into DB: " . mysql_error());
        $rec_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

and for ingredient

```
$ingredient = $_POST['ingredient'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$integer = 0;
while (count($ingredient)>$integer) {
if (($ingredient[$integer] <> "") && ($amount[$integer] <> "")){
$sql =  "INSERT INTO `cafe`.`ingredients` (`ingredient_id`, `ingredient_name`, `ammount`, `rec_id`,)
    VALUES ('', '".$ingredient[$integer]."', '".$amount[$integer]."', '$rec_id')";
mysql_query($sql);
echo $sql."
";
}
else{
echo "ingredient number ".($integer+1)." is missing values and cannot be inserted.";
}
$integer = ($integer + 1);
}
```

when i echo the queries the out put is

```
nsert into recipe (rec_id, Name, Overview,category, Time, Image) values ('', 'demo recipe','no overview','meal','10/12/10 : 13:02:33','http://www.localhost/cafe/pics/demo.gif')
INSERT INTO cafe.ingredients (ingredient_id, ingredient_name, ammount, rec_id,) VALUES ('', 'ingredient one', '3gm', '29')
INSERT INTO cafe.ingredients (ingredient_id, ingredient_name, ammount, rec_id,) VALUES ('', 'ingredient two', '3gm', '29')
INSERT INTO cafe.ingredients (ingredient_id, ingredient_name, ammount, rec_id,) VALUES ('', 'ingredient three', '3gm', '29')
```

but when i see the mysql table or retriew data from ingredient there is no data in ingredient.

Comment: can you please post the definitions for the recipe and the ingredient table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a syntax error in your code:

```
if (($ingredient[$integer]  "") && ($amount[$integer]  ""))
                            ^^                         ^^
```

Looks like you are missing a comparison operator.

Comment: hay this not like this actually it is: if (($ingredient[$integer] <> "") && ($amount[$integer] <> ""))

Comment: that too and you're not checking if there where errors on insert query . please have a look at how to check it with mysql_error() , becouse for example let's say you have an auto increment on ingredient_id , you're sending a null string witch will throw an error becouse ingredient_id should be a number or if you whant to auto_increment don't send ingredient_id at all .

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra `,` after `rec_id`.

Remove it, so it looks like

```
INSERT INTO cafe.ingredients (ingredient_id, ingredient_name, ammount, rec_id) VALUES ('', 'ingredient one', '3gm', '29')
```

And you will be OK

Answer (score 0):

You might want to verify if you are using a BEGIN call and not committing after INSERT. You can refer to http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/MySQL/Using-Transactions-with-MySQL-4.0-and-PHP/

in that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

When insert doesnt throw exceptions and doesnt insert data there are I think a couple of options

1) you use transaction somewhere and rollback it 
2) your select query is bad and data is there, but you just dont select it

Comment: but when i checked data in phpmyadmin there is no record found for ingredient

Comment: well 1) look for uncommited transactions 2) try to delete everything from ingridents tables and run your code, then select * from there, if no exceptions are thrown it would require some magic I think for a 3rd solution

Comment: i delete all the records from recipe as well as ingredients table but still recipe is add but ingredient does't add to the table and queries are correct

Answer (score 0):

remove `cafe` from the query

```
$sql =  "INSERT INTO ingredients (`ingredient_id`, `ingredient_name`, `ammount`, `rec_id`,)
    VALUES ('', '".$ingredient[$integer]."', '".$amount[$integer]."', '$rec_id')";
```